# VBA looping multiple conditions (AND, OR)

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to check multiple conditions and if they are OK, just proceed. Otherwise there should be a message. The macro is run but it doesn't capture errors (e.g. No fund # in column -2) and does not provide with error message as expected. What is wrong?

```
Sub CheckFundsInISAccounts()

'Version 9 change.

Dim c As Range
Dim lstRng As Range
Dim LastRow As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Worksheets("DataFile").Activate
Range("U2").Activate

LastRow = Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).row

Set lstRng = Range("U2", Range("U65536").End(xlUp))


For Each c In lstRng
    If c.Value > 29999 And c.Offset(0, -2).Value = 10 Or 11 Or 12 Or 20 Or 45 Or 60 Or 70 Then
        c.Offset(1, 0).Select

    Else

      MsgBox ("NOT every IS account has a Fund assigned to it. Double-check it")

    End If

Next c


Columns("A:W").Select
Selection.EntireColumn.AutoFit

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`c.Offset(0, -2).Value = 10 Or 11 Or 12 Or 20 Or 45 Or 60 Or 70 Then` is not proper code. You need to do each test individually:

```
c.Offset(0, -2).Value = 10 Or c.Offset(0, -2).Value = 11 Or c.Offset(0, -2).Value = 12 Or c.Offset(0, -2).Value = 20 Or c.Offset(0, -2).Value = 45 Or c.Offset(0, -2).Value = 60 Or c.Offset(0, -2).Value = 70 Then
```

Of course there are more convenient ways, such as putting your valid values in a list and checking if that list contains `c.Offset(0, -2).Value`.

Comment: Hi Andrew, Thank you for prompt and explicit answer. Now my issue is that the data set is large and message box if not the best option for ELSE. How could I get an address of all errors in one message box? Thank you!!!

Comment: If you have a separate question, post it separately like you have done here so other people will see it.

Comment: OK, thank you!!! i will post a separate question on getting address of all errors in one message box. This case is closed.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference in result depending on use of parenthesis

```
If c.Value > 29999 _
And c.Offset(0, -2).Value = 10 _
Or c.Offset(0, -2).Value = 11 _
Or c.Offset(0, -2).Value = 12 _
Or c.Offset(0, -2).Value = 20 _
Or c.Offset(0, -2).Value = 45 _
Or c.Offset(0, -2).Value = 60 _
Or c.Offset(0, -2).Value = 70 Then
```

Will have different results than the following (which may be what you are looking for)

```
If c.Value > 29999 _
And (c.Offset(0, -2).Value = 10 _
    Or c.Offset(0, -2).Value = 11 _
    Or c.Offset(0, -2).Value = 12 _
    Or c.Offset(0, -2).Value = 20 _
    Or c.Offset(0, -2).Value = 45 _
    Or c.Offset(0, -2).Value = 60 _
    Or c.Offset(0, -2).Value = 70) Then
```